# Python And Scrapy Missing Some Link

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi Guys I am new to Scrapy, and a little bit confuse about how parse work.
Here i have 2 code first with 1 parse i get 20 result

```
def start_requests(self):
    url = 'https://news.detik.com/indeks/'
    date = '01/01/2020'

    assert type(url) is str 
    assert type(date) is str 

    max_page = 1
    
    for page in range(1, max_page + 1):
        complete_url = url + str(page) + '?date=' + date
        yield scrapy.Request(complete_url, self.parse)    

def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath('//*[@id="indeks-container"]/article//h3/a/@href').extract()
    
    for link in links:
        yield {'link' : link}
```

but, if i add new parse the result decrease to 18

```
   def start_requests(self):
    url = 'https://news.detik.com/indeks/'
    date = '01/01/2020'

    assert type(url) is str 
    assert type(date) is str 

    max_page = 1
    
    for page in range(1, max_page + 1):
        complete_url = url + str(page) + '?date=' + date
        yield scrapy.Request(complete_url, self.parse)    

def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath('//*[@id="indeks-container"]/article//h3/a/@href').extract()
    
    for link in links:
        yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_content)

def parse_content(self, response):

    yield {
        'title': response.css('.detail__title::text').get().strip()
    }
```

my question is what happen ?

Comment: Maybe there are duplicate urls? Does the log say anything?

Answer (score 0):

There are two exceptions in second case,

the heading of following articles are inside  `.detail_text`  class instead of  `.detail_title`  class

'Bandara Halim Pastikan Penumpang Dapat Kompensasi 100 Persen' and
'Kunjungi Posko Banjir Kemang, Anies Pastikan Kebutuhan Warga Terpenuhi'